# Is GetHashCode just cargo-cult here?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety, httpcontext

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["ctx_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x")]
```

I see this exact code [all](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37932/Simple-Sample-with-Entity-Framework) ... [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619691/entity-framework-objectcontext-with-dependency-injection) ... [the](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx) ... [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702676/server-side-equivalent-of-httpcontext) but I must be overlooking something. It's common in responses to these posts to question the appropriateness of using HttpContext, but no one points out that GetHashCode is redundant and a fixed string will do.

What am I overlooking here?

---

EDIT: The question is, GetHashCode() will be the same for every HttpContext.Current, so why use GetHashCode() in the four links I provided? Some of them are posts with quite a bit of work put into them, so I feel like perhaps they are addressing some threading or context issue I'm overlooking. I don't see why just HttpContext.Current.Items["ctx_"] wouldn't do exactly the same.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Why use GetHashCode? How is this different than Items["ctx_"]?

Comment: I dont see how thats different then Items["myKey"]. It can only make app harder to debug if you use keys you dont specify yourself.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that this is used to create a key, that even in a large system with many programmers and many things getting put in to the `Items` collection, will still be unique.

Comment: @EladLachmi: Unless other programmers will come up with same solution :)

Comment: @Peri: True. You could just generate a `Guid` to the same effect.

Comment: Ah, yes. Defense against a lack of randomness in a human-selected name. Good point, Elad, and right on with the response Peri. I've seen exactly the same solution all over. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is horrible. For one, `HttpContext.Current.Items` is local to the current `HttpContext` anyway so need to attempt to make the keys "more unique". Second, depending on how this technique is used the keys will collide once in a while causing spurious, undebuggable failures.

If you *need* a unique key (maybe because you are developing a library), use a saner solution like `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`. This is guaranteed to work and even simpler.

Comment: After a week of the question hanging out there you both answered at almost exactly the same time :) I selected this for the suggestion of a Guid and the "more unique" comment.

Comment: I wonder how you later get the value under this key. You would have to store the key somewhere for the life of application. Way too complicated. Just use "my_super_duper_library_that_does_something_ctxt" as the key.

Comment: You can store the Guid in a static variable that is accessible from all pieces of code using it. (I do not recommend it, nor do I recommend against it - it is just an option).

Answer (score 1):

So to answer your question :)

It doesn't make much sense to use GetHashcode for creating key.
Authors of posts you gave links to probably wanted to create key that will be unique. But doing this doesn't stop other team member to use same key somewhere else in the code base.

I think it's better to just use handwritten long keys. Instead of

```
["ctx_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x")]
```

just use

```
["object_context_key"]
```

or something like that. That way you know what it is exactly (and that may be usefull in for example post mortem debugging) and I also think that if you have to come up with some long key it is possible that it will be 'more unique' then the one with GetHashCode.